# How to make dictionary extension-methods?

Tags: c#, dictionary, extension-methods

I'm trying to write a `Dictionary` extension that works independently of the data types of Key/Value. I tried pass it by using  the `object` data type, assuming that it will works with any type.

My code:

```
 public static class DictionaryExtensionsClass
    {
        public static void AddFormat(this Dictionary< ?? unknow type/*object*/, ??unknow type/*object*/> Dic, ??unknow type/*object*/ Key, string str, params object[] arglist)
        {
            Dic.Add(Key, String.Format(str, arglist));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You just make the method generic:

```
public static void AddFormat<TKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, string> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    string formatString,
    params object[] argList)
{
    dictionary.Add(key, string.Format(formatString, argList));
}
```

Note that it's only generic in the *key* type as the value would *have* to be `string` (or potentially `object` or an interface that `string` implements, I guess) given that you're going to add a string value to it.

Unfortunately you can't really express the constraint of "only allow value types where `string` is a valid value" in a generic type constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) I have changed the code, but to a variable of type `Dictionary<WaringType, string>();` where `WaringType` is a `enum`, I get an error: `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<myclass.WaringType,string>' does not contain a definition for 'AddFormat' and no extension method 'AddFormat' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<myclass.WaringType,string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: And as I'm calling the method: `ErrMessages.AddFormat(WaringType.FatalError, "{0} foo {1} baa etc", a.Name, a.Value);`

Comment: Make sure there's a `using` statement to make the class with the extension method visible if you are working in a different namespace. Try calling your extension method explicitly as `DictionaryExtensionsClass.AddFormat(theDictionary, key, format, ...);` to check the visibility.

Comment: @Wormbo: Thanks. When I see the `DictionaryExtensionsClass` on autcompletaion, I see the method names and my typo. I when rewrite the code suggest By Jon Skeet I added a `t` on Forma**t**tAdd() method name. Sorry sorry for inconvinience.